# How can I determine the maximum requests per second that my server running an ExpressJS application can handle?

Tags: node.js, express, http, stress-testing

This is a general question so there is no code.

I have a nodejs Express app running in AWS EC2 instance which has 2 vCPU cores and 4GB memory. I want to know the limit of this server so that I can know how many clients this backend server can handle.

Say that this nodejs Express app has 10 api endpoints, and each endpoint is doing some business logic and / or database queries, what is some standard methods for me to determine the how many workload this server can handle?

I want to know some quantitative values, like the minimum number of requests per second that will use up the CPU and memory resources.

Here are some thoughts:

1. I can run test scripts in another server to send http requests to the api endpoints in this server. Since I write these test scripts, I can control how fast requests are send out to this server.
2. In the backend server, I need to monitor how well my nodejs express app is dealing with these incoming requests:

   - I can use `htop` to view the cpu and memory usage in real time.
   - I can time the individual api endpoints, to see how many milliseconds each request-response cycle is taking. If an increase in processing time is observed for the same type of requests over time, then there must be a shortage of free CPU time or memory.

These are just some initial thoughts.
I want to know:

1. What are the standard way of doing these kind of stress tests in the industry? There must be mature ways of doing this.
2. What are some good libraries / tools to use for this kind of tasks?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't have to write the test script. There are several out there that already do what you want. They fall under the category of "stress testing" or "load testing". The two most popular ones in node are artillery (https://www.npmjs.com/package/artillery) and autocannon (https://www.npmjs.com/package/autocannon). I've even written one myself: httpstress (https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpstress)